# Get dictionary keys for given batched values - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, nonetype, jax

I defined a dictionary `A` and would like to find the keys given a batch of values `a`:

```
def dictionary(r):
 return dict(enumerate(r))

def get_key(val, my_dict):
   for key, value in my_dict.items():
      if np.array_equal(val,value):
          return key
    

 # dictionary
 A = jnp.array([[0, 0],[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])
 A = dictionary(A)

 a = jnp.array([[[1, 1],[2, 2], [3,3]],[[0, 0],[3, 3], [2,2]]])
 keys = jax.vmap(jax.vmap(get_key, in_axes=(0,None)), in_axes=(0,None))(a, A)
```

The expected output should be:
`keys = [[1,2,3],[0,3,2]]`

Why am I getting `None`as an output?

Comment: Well you are checking if any of the values in A (e.g. [0,0]) is equal to a (which is three dimensional matrix). And this is never the case.

Comment: I tried using a double jax vmap over the inputs, but  I keep getting None as an output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAX transforms like `vmap` work by *tracing* the function, meaning they replace the value with an abstract representation of the value to extract the sequence of operations encoded in the function (See [How to think in JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/thinking_in_jax.html) for a good intro to this concept).

What this means is that to work correctly with `vmap`, a function can only use JAX methods, not numpy methods, so your use of `np.array_equal` breaks the abstraction.

Unfortunately, there's not really any replacement for it, because there's no mechanism to look up an abstract JAX value in a concrete Python dictionary. If you want to do dict lookups of JAX values, you should avoid transforms and just use Python loops:

```py
keys = jnp.array([[get_key(x, A) for x in row] for row in a])
```

On the other hand, I suspect this is more of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); your goal is not to look up dictionary values within a jax transform, but rather to solve some problem. Perhaps you should ask a question about how to solve the problem, rather than how to get around an issue with the solution you have tried.

But if you're willing to not directly use the dict, an alternative `get_key` implementation that is compatible with JAX might look something like this:

```py
def get_key(val, my_dict):
  keys = jnp.array(list(my_dict.keys()))
  values = jnp.array(list(my_dict.values()))
  return keys[jnp.where((values == val).all(-1), size=1)]
```